# Unsupported locator strategy appears while running appium and protractor

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, protractor, appium

I want to automate my testcases using Appium and Protractor in Ipad simulator, when i run protractor protractor.config.js i got this error :
unsupported locator strategy : accesibility id (status : 13) at webdriverError

[image: config file]
[image: Locator strategy]

I'm using :

- Appium for IOS version (V 1.4.13)
- Node (V 4.3.2)
- protractor (V 3.2.2)

Here my config file :

Comment: Could you show what is inside the protractor config? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe : i put it in the question it self. Thanks

Comment: @alecxe : i have a new problem, when i make the recording with appium the ipad simulator isn't refreshed at all even if i tap refresh and when i make replay also, nothing is replayed after recording. Otherwise the code is genereted with the full xpath or name. 
And that same code when i put in my protractor scripts it's not working.